# My curtain is being pulled toward the mesh. Is this due to bernoulli's principle?

Tags: bernoulli-equation

When my window is open, the wind from outside blows the curtains into the room, but sometimes after that it's pulled towards the mesh. It doesn't happen every time, so I think this happens randomly. Does this happen when the speed of the wind decreases causing the pressure on the curtains from outside to increase, or does it have nothing to do with that? I'm not really a physics expert or anything and I didn't really study bernoulli's principle except very vaguely at school. I just know that when the velocity of the fluid increases, the pressure it exerts decreases and vice-versa.[image: curtains]

Answer (score 1):

The most likely explanation is that the wind moving past your building shifts direction for short periods of time, in gusts. So air that wants to blow in one of your windows (and out of another) most of the time will instead be wanting to blow in another window, and out of the one you are watching- which will push the curtains up against the screen on that window. Then the wind shifts back, and the curtains blow in again.